# Show that any finite nilpotent group of square free order is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

Show that any finite nilpotent group of square free order is cyclic.

Hint: Suppose G is such a group. Any Sylow subgroup of G is of prime order.

Hint: Any finite nilpotent group is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Hint: Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Any idea,

Comment: Ii think those hints are aplenty. Just mimick the proof of  $C_3\times C_5\simeq C_{15}$.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you take a look at [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).